# Prove derivative: dot product and cross product

Tags: calculus

> Prove that $\frac{d}{dt} (r \cdot (r' \times r'')) = r \cdot (r' \times r''') $.

So far I have

$$(r \cdot (r'\times r'')) = r' \cdot (r' \times r'') + r \cdot (r'' \times r'' + r' \times r''') \\
              = r' \cdot (r' \times r'') + r \cdot (r' \times r''')$$

Can't figure out how to narrow it down from here... any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r' \times r''$ is perpendicular to $r'$, so its dot product with $r'$ will be zero. Alternatively, $a \cdot (b \times c) = c \cdot (a \times b) $, so $r' \cdot (r' \times r'') = r'' \cdot (r' \times r') = 0$.